# Jrocket GC JVM parameter is not working in JDK 8

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, jvm

I Have configure GC parameter in jrockit-jdk1.6.0_33 which is below

```
-Xgc:pausetime -XpauseTarget:201 -XXgcTrigger=20 -Xgc:gencon -Xverbose:gcreport -XXkeepAreaRatio:50 -XXcompactRatio:10 -Xverbose:compaction -Xverbose:gcpause -Xverbose:memdbg

-Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcinterval=600000 -verbose:memory -xverboselog:verbose-jrockit-server.log -Xverbosetimestamp
```

Now I have migrated my application from jrockit-jdk1.6.0_33 to JDK8_66 .
But it is not working in JDK8. And JDK 8 has already bundle with jrocket.
so what is alternate of this GC JVM parameter in JDK 8 ?

Comment: have you read the [hotspot gc tuning guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
-XX:+UseG1GC
```

That's pretty much it. If you want to see the details of GC etc. then you probably want to have:

```
-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime
```

Note that the GC info is being migrated in Java 9 to yet another different format and set of flags; see [JEP 271](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/271) for more details.